# Program in Java not reading a specific line of code

Tags: java, android

This is the Overall Code for reference:

```
 package com.example.scoutingapp2019v9;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class EndgameEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioButton end_level1;
    RadioButton end_level2;
    RadioButton end_level3;
    String[] data;
    String fileName;
    String path;
    String[] labels;
    Button savedata;
    EditText comments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_endgame_entry);


        data = new String[14];
//        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        String[] autoEntryData = intent.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
//        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
//            data[i] = autoEntryData[i];
//        }
        labels = new String[]{"Team Number", "Event", "Match Number", "Alliance", "Start Position", "Exited HabZone", "Number of HatchPanels Placed in Sandstorm", "Number of Cargo Placed in Sandstorm", "Teleop Number of HatchPanels Placed in Rockets", "Teleop Number of Cargo Placed in Rockets", "Teleop Number of HatchPanels Placed in CargoShip", "Teleop Number of Cargo Placed in CargoShip", "End Position", "Comments"};
        savedata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savedata);
        final RadioButton rb9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level1);
        final RadioButton rb10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level2);
        final RadioButton rb11 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level3);
        final RadioButton rb12 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.end_level_0);
        comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comments);
        savedata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (rb9.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 1");
                } else if (rb10.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 2");
                } else if (rb11.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("Level 3");
                } else if (rb12.isSelected()) {
                    data[12] = ("DNF");
                }
                data[13] = comments.getText().toString();
                saveData(data, labels);
            }
        });
    }
    private void saveData(String[] saveData, String[] saveLabels){
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/TeamData2019/";//temporarily without subfolder
        fileName = data[0] + "_" + data[1] + "_" + data[2] + ".json";
        try{
            new File(path).mkdir();
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/TeamData2019/" + data[1] + '/';
            new File(path).mkdir();
            File file = new File(path + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for(int i = 0; i < saveData.length; i++){
                obj.put(saveLabels[i],saveData[i]);
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
        fileWriter.write(obj.toString());
        fileWriter.flush();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am having a particular problem with these lines:

```
try{
                new File(path).mkdir();
                path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents/TeamData2019/" + data[1] + '/';
                new File(path).mkdir();
                File file = new File(path + fileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for(int i = 0; i < saveData.length; i++){
                    obj.put(saveLabels[i],saveData[i]);
            }
```

Because whatever I try to do, the program will not read those lines and skips over them, and android studio itself says that the result of the lines is ignored (And I confirmed this using method breakpoints). I have tried changing up the brackets around the code, but nothing is working. It may have just been an over sight by me, as I am still a beginner in this language.
Does anyone have any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: How do you know it skips those lines? Do you print out any log statements?

Comment: Its cause may be related to statement **fileName = data[0] + "_" + data[1] + "_" + data[2] + ".json"**; In here İf data array has not element 0,1 or 2 then it throws error. So other part of the segment not goes on. Move this line into your try ctach block and see if the problem occurs because of them.

Comment: this is how the try catch block works, when there is an error/exception the code jumps to the catch block.

Comment: Programs don't 'read' their own lines of code. They *execute* them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the file had already been created, as user hfarhanahmed pointed out, I deleted the previous file that the program created and the program started working again.